# Find difference between two multi dimensional lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scipy, google-api-python-client

I would like to find intersection between multi dimensional list with first element, but I am not able to find solution.

Example :

```
a = [[greg ,1.2 ,400 ,234] [top ,9.0 ,5.1 ,2300] [file ,5.7 ,2.2, 900] [stop, 1.6 ,6.7 ,200] 

b = [[hall,5.2 ,460 ,234] [line ,5.3 ,5.91 ,100] [file ,2.7 ,3.3, 6.4] [stop, 6.6 ,5.7 ,230]
```

What I need :

1.element not in a but in b , I want to compare only with `element[0]`

Expecting output = `[[hall,5.2 ,460 ,234] [line ,5.3 ,5.91 ,100]]`

2.element not in b but in a ,I want to compare only with `element[0]`

Expecting output = `[greg ,1.2 ,400 ,234]`

Then append missing list to a and b vice versa.

I have sample code, but not working.

```
at = map(tuple,a)
bt = map(tuple,b)

st1 = set(at)
st2 = set(bt)

s1 = st1.intersection(st2)
s2 = st2.intersection(st1)
```

Comment: your second condition is not right, you should be expecting `[greg ,1.2 ,400 ,234]` and `[top ,9.0 ,5.1 ,2300]`

Comment: Thank you for correcting yes , The expected output is [[greg ,1.2 ,400 ,234] [top ,9.0 ,5.1 ,2300]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two dicts and find the *set difference* of the keys, where the keys are each first element:

```
a = [["greg", 1.2, 400, 234], ["top", 9.0, 5.1, 2300], ["file", 5.7, 2.2, 900], ["stop", 1.6, 6.7, 200]]

b = [["hall", 5.2, 460, 234], ["line", 5.3, 5.91, 100], ["file", 2.7, 3.3, 6.4], ["stop", 6.6, 5.7, 230]]

d1 = {sub[0]: sub for sub in a}
d2 = {sub[0]: sub for sub in b}

print([d2[k] for k in d2.keys() - d1])
print([d1[k] for k in d1.keys() - d2])
```

Output:

```
[['hall', 5.2, 460, 234], ['line', 5.3, 5.91, 100]]
[['top', 9.0, 5.1, 2300], ['greg', 1.2, 400, 234]]
```

The correct output is `[['top', 9.0, 5.1, 2300], ['greg', 1.2, 400, 234]]` not just `[['greg', 1.2, 400, 234]]` as per your expected output in your question.

The equivalent python 2 code would use need to use *viewkeys*:

```
print([d2[k] for k in d2.viewkeys() - d1])
print([d1[k] for k in d1.viewkeys() - d2])
```

Comment: Great it worked. Thank you so much and Many thanks ! Padraic Cunningham!

Comment: @danidee, busy life these days so not as much time to spend on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [["greg" ,1.2 ,400 ,234], ["top" ,9.0 ,5.1 ,2300], ["file" ,5.7 ,2.2, 900], ["stop", 1.6 ,6.7 ,200]]
b = [["hall",5.2 ,460 ,234], ["line" ,5.3 ,5.91 ,100], ["file" ,2.7 ,3.3, 6.4], ["stop", 6.6 ,5.7 ,230]]

b_prime = list()
i=0
for key in a:
    if key[0] == b[i][0]:
        i = i + 1
        continue
    print "entry ",key, " is not in a"
    b_prime.append(key)
    i = i + 1

a_prime = list()
i=0
for key in b:
    if key[0] == a[i][0]:
        i = i + 1
        continue
    print "entry ",key, " is not in b"
    a_prime.append(key)
    i = i + 1


print " "
print a
print b
print "need to add these to b", b_prime
print "need to add these to a", a_prime

i=0
for key in a_prime:
    a.append(b[i])
    i = i + 1

i=0
for key in b_prime:
    b.append(a[i])
    i = i + 1

print " "
print a
print b
```

Comment: Hi Jim, code returns nothing .   b_prime = list()
i=0
for key in a:
    if key[0] == b[i][0]:
        i = i + 1
        continue
        print ("entry ",key, " is not in b",b_prime.append(key))


a_prime = list()
i=0
for key in b:
    if key[0] == a[i][0]:
        i = i + 1
        continue
        print ("entry ",key, " is not in b",a_prime.append(key))

Comment: But if the order is different , I am getting this output :need to add these to b [['file', 5.7, 2.2, 900], ['greg', 1.2, 400, 234], ['top', 9.0, 5.1, 2300]]
need to add these to a [['hall', 5.2, 460, 234], ['line', 5.3, 5.91, 100], ['file', 2.7, 3.3, 6.4]]

Comment: Suppose the order is :  a = [['file' ,5.7 ,2.2, 900],['greg' ,1.2 ,400 ,234], ['top' ,9.0 ,5.1 ,2300],  ['stop', 1.6 ,6.7 ,200]]

b = [['hall',5.2 ,460 ,234], ['line' ,5.3 ,5.91 ,100], ['file' ,2.7 ,3.3, 6.4], ['stop', 6.6 ,5.7 ,230]]